# Why I get error in DO$$ - END$$ statement in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I get error:

> pq: syntax error at or near "DO"

My simple statement:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  _iter int;
BEGIN
  _iter:= -1;
  /* some logic */
END
$$;
```

PS: I commented out the logic to understand what the problem is

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that? Not all SQL clients understand dollar quoting

Comment: I am writing a request to Grafana

Comment: The syntax is fine, must be a problem with Grafana then. Maybe it only supports certain statements

Comment: Have you tried the function in `psql` to see if it works?

Comment: Grafana uses `$` notation for the variables, so those `$$` can be interpolated by Grafana first. Use query inspector to see SQL, which actually generated and executed - eventually use escaping to create expected SQL.